# Make a method parameter a generic or wildcard.

Tags: java, generics

I have the following method

```
    private void test(String A, String B, <?> C) throws Exception {
       //.....
    }
```

I would like C to be a generic parameter or anything (int, long, double, etc.). What is the right way to do that?

Comment: No C will generally be a Primitive Data Type - int, long, double, etc.

Comment: `private static <T> void test(String A, String B, T C) throws Exception { ... }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, don't name your variables as upper case letters. Second, like so -

```
private <TYPE> void test(String a, String b, TYPE c) throws Exception {
   //.....
   // c is of the generic type TYPE.
}
```

Any primitive types used will be auto-boxed to their Object wrapper types (e.g. double will be Double, etc).

Comment: Note that primitive variables will be autoboxed here.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use generics for that task. It would make far more sense to handle them separately, by overloading that method for different primitive types:

```
private void test(String A, String B, int C) throws Exception { }
private void test(String A, String B, long C) throws Exception { }
private void test(String A, String B, float C) throws Exception { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
private <T> void test(String A, String B, T C) throws Exception {
   //.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the generic `Object`

```
private void test(String A, String B, Object C) throws Exception {
   //.....
}

Something.test("A", "B", C);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use both generic methods and wildcards in tandem. Here is the method Collections.copy():

```
class Collections {
    public static <T> void copy(List<T> dest, List<? extends T> src) {
    ...
}
```

A great resource on generic methods can be found here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html

Back to your code ...

```
public <T> void test(T o)
{
   ...
}
```